# iPhone keyboard ignores second request for Numeric and Punctuation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a method that creates a local textfield and pops up the keyboard ( of a given type ) to fill the field. I call this 4 times each following the input done event of the previous.

The first time i call it with the default keyboard and the following three are with the UIKeyBoardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation keyboard. The weird thing is that the third call ( second of UIKeyBoardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation ) brings up the Default keyboard and the fourth brings up UIKeyBoardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation again.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Crufy's answer to this question also solves this problem:
[becomeFirstResponder Doesn't respect Keyboard settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214311/becomefirstresponder-doesnt-respect-keyboard-settings)

Returning NO from

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
```

in the delegate fixes it.